# Python: Corkscrew method to define a n - parastic number

Tags: python

Assignment: Write a function corkscrew that takes two natural numbers n and k. The function must return the n-parasitic number that ends with the digit k that results from applying the corkscrew method. The function may assume that n and k are both single-digit natural numbers, with k≥n.

Example:

```
corkscrew (5, 7)
                  5 x 7 = 35
                 5 x 57 = 285
                5 x 857 = 4285
               5 x 2857 = 14285
              5 x 42857 = 214285
             5 x 142857 = 714285
```

Problem : with my code in the for loop the number and thus the result res doesn't change or evolve to the n - parastic number.

```
def parasitic(number):
    """
    >>> parasitic(179487)
    4
    >>> parasitic(142857)
    5
    >>> parasitic(105263157894736842)
    2
    >>> parasitic(1234)
    0
    """

    for n in range(2, 11):
        res = n * number
        if str(number)[-1] + str(number)[:-1] == str(res):
            return n
    return 0

def corkscrew(n, number):
    """
    >>> corkscrew(4, 7)
    179487
    >>> corkscrew(5, 7)
    142857
    >>> corkscrew(2, 2)
    105263157894736842
    """


    res = n * number
    count = 0

    for i in range(1, n):
        res = n * (str(res)[-i:] + str(number))
        count += 1
        if parasitic(number) == n:
            return rotateLeft(res)



def rotateLeft(number):
    """
    >>> rotateLeft(717948)
    179487
    >>> rotateLeft(142857)
    428571
    >>> rotateLeft(105263157894736842)
    52631578947368421
    """

    k = str(number)
    letter = k[:1]
    numb = k[1:]
    resultaat = str(numb) + str(letter)
    return int(resultaat)
```

Comment: can you also provide parasitic() & rotateLeft() definition ?

Comment: @MaheshKaria: I have added the def parasitic(): which works fine.

Comment: I just needed to run this locally so I needed those functions

Comment: @MaheshKaria: I also added the def rotateLeft():

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question that works:

```
def corkscrew(n, number):
    """
    >>> corkscrew(4, 7)
    179487
    >>> corkscrew(5, 7)
    142857
    >>> corkscrew(2, 2)
    105263157894736842
    """


    res = n * number
    count = 0

    for i in range(0, 65):
        numb = (str(res)[-i:] + str(number))
        numb = int(numb)
        res = n * numb
        count += 1
        if parasitic(numb) == n:
            return numb
```